# Javascript placing graphs into different tables with CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

My code below is intended so that the user has 2 boxes to where they need to insert different graphs. If the user wants a graph set in the first box, he should press the button in the first box, if he wants a graph set in the second box, he should press the button in the second box.

Currently my code will place all graphs within the first box, is there a code I can implement so that it knows what box should the graphs be placed in response to which button had been pressed within the box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;

  table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 2px black solid;
font: 12px sans-serif;
}

td {
border: 1px black solid;
padding: 5px;
}
}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 20%;
 float: middle;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
  <table style="width:65%;height:850px">
    <tr><td align="center" id="blockOne">
    <p><button onclick="addGraph()">Create Graph/Chart</button></p>
    <tr><td align="center" id="blockTwo">
    <p><button onclick="addGraph()">Create Graph/Chart</button></p>
  </table>

  <div id="addGraphModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <table style="width:100%"; id="graphTable">
      <p><button onclick="generateBar()">Bar Chart</button></p>
      <p><button onclick="generateLine()">Line Chart</button></p>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
<!-- On button press, the Modal is created  -->
var modalGraph = document.getElementById('addGraphModal');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
function addGraph() {
 modalGraph.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
 modalGraph.style.display = "none";

$("#graphTable").empty();
}

  function generateBar() {

   $("#blockOne").empty();
  $('#blockOne').append('<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>');

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
         animationEnabled: true,
         theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
         title:{
          text: "Top Oil Reserves"
         },
         axisY: {
          title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
         },
         data: [{
          type: "column",
          showInLegend: true,
          legendMarkerColor: "grey",
          legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
          dataPoints: [
           { y: 300878, label: "Venezuela" },
           { y: 266455,  label: "Saudi" },
           { y: 169709,  label: "Canada" },
           { y: 158400,  label: "Iran" },
           { y: 142503,  label: "Iraq" },
           { y: 101500, label: "Kuwait" },
           { y: 97800,  label: "UAE" },
           { y: 80000,  label: "Russia" }
          ]
         }]
        });
        chart.render();
}
  function generateLine() {
      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
       animationEnabled: true,
       theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
       title:{
        text: "Top Oil Reserves"
       },
       axisY: {
        title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
       },
       data: [{
        type: "line",
        showInLegend: true,
        legendMarkerColor: "grey",
        legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
        dataPoints: [
         { y: 300878, label: "Venezuela" },
         { y: 266455,  label: "Saudi" },
         { y: 169709,  label: "Canada" },
         { y: 158400,  label: "Iran" },
         { y: 142503,  label: "Iraq" },
         { y: 101500, label: "Kuwait" },
         { y: 97800,  label: "UAE" },
         { y: 80000,  label: "Russia" }
        ]
       }]
      });
      chart.render();
    }
</script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like you are updating same chart  and the chartContainer again and again. Having different chart and chart-container will work fine in your case.

Comment: @VishwasR the whole purpose is that depending on what button is pressed in the tables, the chart container is changed to fit it that choice so chartcontainer1 for table box 1 and chart container 2 for table box 2

Comment: Thats correct that there should be 2 different containers container1, container2. But in the code that you have shared has only one container `chartContainer` which is child of blockOne because of which you are not getting chart in blockTwo. Try adding one more container to blockTwo.